# In csh or tcsh, is this 'set variables' available?

Tags: variables, assign, csh

I have used the csh/tcsh script before I learned bash.
I've heard that csh has some issues compared to bash.
However, my code was mostly written in csh, so I need to address this problem.
I've simplified my problem as follows:

```
echo test1 test2 | awk -v col=color 'BEGIN{while((getline<col)>0){color[++i]=$1};}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("select \\\052/%s ; color %s ; ",i,color[i])}}'
```

where color file includes

```
red
blue
green
```

the output ; this is fine

```
select \*/1 ; color red ; select \*/2 ; color blue ;
```

but my problem is that i want to assign a variable (aaa) having the output like the command

```
set aaa = `echo test1 test2 | awk -v col=color 'BEGIN{while((getline<col)>0){color[++i]=$1};}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("select \\\052/%s ; color %s ; ",i,color[i])}}'`
```

it fails in csh.
Could u let me know how to solve the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: set aaa = `echo test1 test2 | awk -v col=color 'BEGIN{while((getline<col)>0){color[++i]=$1};}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("select \\052/%s ; color %s ; ",i,color[i])}}'` ; By removing one escape character, i got the result that i want. It's different between bash and csh. In bash, it didn't expand the wild card. but in csh/tcsh, it expand the files.

Comment: FYI, it is different on bash and csh/tcsh ; one and three slashes expand in shell it makes problem in tcsh ; two slashes are right
    # echo "\052" "\\052" "\\\052"
    # tcsh    *     \052    \*
    # bash   \052   \052   \\052